# how to navigate from one viewcontroller to second viewcontroller in xamarin ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Failed to marshal the Objective-C object 0x7a71ed40 (type: SecondViewController). Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance (because the type 'NavigationApp.SecondViewController' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument).

I have a ViewController and secondViewController, When I hookup storyboard to secondViewController, the above error is shown. But without hookup with secondViewController, its working fine.

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for some answer to your problem you might want to format it correctly and respect your readers.
You are literally throwing your error message to our face.

Have you tried to follow this guide ? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/ios_code_only/